# Why are subviews not visible when I set UIStackView distribution to equalspacing?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uistackview

I want to put a group of custom views inside a `UIStackView` horizontally.
Each of the subviews has a width and height `equal to constant` constraint:

```
 let stack = UIStackView(frame: frameRect)
 stack.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.horizontal
 stack.distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.equalSpacing
        
 stack.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 40, bottom: 0, right: 40)
 stack.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true

 for i in 1...3 {
     let numberView = RotatingNumberView()
     numberView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(cellSize))
     numberView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(cellSize))
     numberViews.append(numberView)
     stack.addArrangedSubview(numberView)
  }
```

If I change to `fillEqually` distribution, the subviews are shown, but their widths are stretched to fill the stackView.

I guess it has something to do with hugging or compression resistence priority, but setting these in subview doesn't work.

What is happening here?

Comment: Firstly, why are you not using storyboard ???

Comment: @UmerFarooq I have to add the subviews programmatically, because the number of subviews cannot be determined beforehand.

Comment: For all distributions except the `fillEqually` distribution, the stack view uses each arranged view’s `intrinsicContentSize` property when calculating its size along the stack’s axis.

Comment: If the subviews are dynamic, isnt Collection View a good option here?

Comment: could you please add some picture?
Your output right now?
and what you want it to be? if possible?

Comment: I solved this by overriding `intrinsicContentSize` as @Rahul suggested.

Comment: @NeoWang I added the comment to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all distributions except the `fillEqually`, the stack view uses each arranged view’s `intrinsicContentSize` property when calculating its size along the stack’s axis.

So overriding this property will work.

```
  override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize { return CGSize(your values) }
```